Add comments from the Staging Ground to the activity tab
I'm not sure if this should be tagged as feature-request or bug, but I wonder if it was a deliberate decision, a technical necessity, or an oversight that comments on questions in Staging Ground are not shown in the profile's activity.
Anyway, I'd like to see them there, because I frequently use the activity history to check back on stuff I participated in.
